# Start script to run app

Tags: applications, scripts

I have a device connected to a TV, I need that when I start the device it automatically opens the player and plays a video.

I thought that I could do the same as linux, writing a bash script, it would be relatively easy and it would start at startup, well linux already has such a startup script. But I can't find the /etc directory.

On the other hand, how are the orders of the app? To be able to write it in the script? And your options.

Also if there is another option I would like to know it.

Thanks.

Comment: You wrote "I have a device" what device, model and manufacturer? Are you sure this device is running Android? Do you have rooted that device?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MacroDroid shell script non-root location permission denied](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233722/macrodroid-shell-script-non-root-location-permission-denied)